# Volume of $k$-simplex in $n$-dimensions ($n \ne k$)?

Tags: geometry, volume, simplex, polytopes

A simplex is the convex hull of a set of vertices. In $\mathbb{R}^n$, the $k$-simplex with vertices $\vec{x}_0,\dots,\vec{x}_k$, $\vec{x}_i \in \mathbb{R}^n$, is the set of points:

$$S = \left\{ \theta_0 \vec{x}_0 + \dots + \theta_k \vec{x}_k \middle| \sum_{i=0}^n \theta_i = 1 \text{ and } \forall_i \theta_i \ge 0  \right\}$$

In general, what is the volume (or content) of $S$? Wikipedia only gives the volume in the case $k=n$, but I am also interested in $k<n$ or $k>n$.

In the particular, I am very interested in $k=n-1$, if any simplifications are possible.

Comment: There is no way to embed a $k$-simplex in $\Bbb R^n$ for $k > n$.

Comment: @Travis why not? just add more vertices.

Comment: What happens when you have $3$ vertices in $\Bbb R^1$?

Answer (score 2):

There's a simple tool for this: First, by translating, we may assume $\newcommand{\bfe}{{\bf e}} \newcommand{\bfx}{{\bf x}} \bfx_0 = {\bf 0}$. The $k$-dimensional volume $\left|\left| \bfx_1 \wedge \cdots \wedge \bfx_k \right|\right|$ of the [parallelotope](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallelepiped) determined by the vectors $ \bfx_1, \ldots, \bfx_k$ is given by the square root of the *Gram determinant*, that is, the determinant of the [*Gram matrix*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gramian_matrix)
$$ \pmatrix{\bfx_1^T \\ \vdots \\ \bfx_k^T} \pmatrix{\bfx_1 & \cdots & \bfx_k}
=
\pmatrix{
\langle \bfx_1, \bfx_1 \rangle & \cdots & \langle \bfx_1, \bfx_k \rangle \\
\vdots & & \vdots \\
\langle \bfx_k, \bfx_1 \rangle & \cdots & \langle \bfx_k, \bfx_k \rangle
} .
$$

The volume of the $k$-simplex $S$ determined by $\bfx_1 , \ldots , \bfx_k$ is a fraction of this:
$$\color{#bf0000}{\boxed{\operatorname{vol}(S) = \frac{1}{k!} \left|\left| \bfx_1 \wedge \cdots \wedge \bfx_k \right|\right| }}.$$ (One can verify directly that $\tfrac{1}{k!}$ is the right coefficient by computing the volume of the standard $k$-simplex with vertices $\bfe_1, \ldots, \bfe_k$, where $(\bfe_a)$ is the standard basis of $\Bbb R^n$.)

In the special case $k = n - 1$, $\left|\left| \bfx_1 \wedge \cdots \wedge \bfx_{n - 1} \right|\right|$ is the length of the vector $\ast (\bfx_1 \wedge \cdots \wedge \bfx_{n - 1})$ given by formally evaluating the determinant
$$
\det \pmatrix{
x_{11} & \cdots & x_{1n} \\
\vdots & & \vdots \\
x_{n-1, 1} & \cdots & x_{n - 1, n} \\
\bfe_1 & \cdots & \bfe_n
} .
$$
For the case $n = 3$, this formal determinant is just the usual cross product of vectors in $\Bbb R^3$, and indeed, the map $(\bfx_1, \ldots, \bfx_{n - 1}) \mapsto \ast (\bfx_1 \wedge \cdots \wedge \bfx_{n - 1})$ is sometimes called an [$(n - 1)$-fold cross product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_product#Multilinear_algebra).

Comment: Dear Travis, your formula displayed in red is false. The correct formula is
$$vol(S)=\frac {1}{k!}||\bfx_1∧⋯∧\bfx_k||$$
By the way, mathematics is a [harsh mistress](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Moon_Is_a_Harsh_Mistress) : never say "it's easy to see" in her presence... – Georges Elencwajg 7 mins ago

Comment: Thanks for catching the missing $!$, Georges; I've folded the correction into the answer.