# Volume of $(n-1)$- simplex in $n$-dimension.

Tags: linear-algebra, volume, simplex

[This](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1742296/volume-of-k-simplex-in-n-dimensions-n-ne-k/1742348#1742348) post gives a general way to calculate $k$-simplex in $n$-dimensional space with $k\leq n$. My question is, if $k=n-1$ and give vertices $v_{0}, \cdots, v_{n-1}$ are linearly independent, can we show that the simplex $S$ generated by $v_{0}, \cdots , v_{n-1}$ has a volume $Vol(S) = \frac{1}{n!}\det\begin{pmatrix}{\bf v}_{0} & \cdots & {\bf v}_{n-1}\end{pmatrix}$?

Comment: Surely the volume is zero? The (affine) dimension of the set $\operatorname{aff} \{ v_0,...,v_{n-1} \}$ is $n-1$. For example, if $n=2$ we can take the simplex generated by $e_1,e_2$ which is just s line segment and hence has measure zero.

Comment: @copper.hat Oh, I think the case when we calculate the volume of it as that in the some $n-1$-dimensional hyperplane.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is a direct consequence of the Cayley-Menger determinant.

Comment: Thanks! I got it.